# PostgreSQL - mounting csv / other file - type volumes/tablespaces

Tags: postgresql, csv

In few other DB engines I can easily extract (part  of) table to single file.
Then if needed I can 'mount' this file as regular table. Querying is obviously slow but this is very useful

I wonder if similar stuff is possible with psql ?

I know COPY FROM/TO function - but for bigger tables I need to wait ages in order to copy records from CSV

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) to access (read) a CSV file on the database server as if it were a table.